# When using `-popUpMenuPositioningItem:atLocation:inView:` to programmatically attach menus to buttons how do you get the selected menu item?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton, nsmenu

I have a button and in the button's action method I programmatically create a menu using, `-popUpMenuPositioningItem:atLocation:inView:`.

How can I get the menu item that the user selected? If I was doing this with `NSPopUpButton` it would be a simple case of calling `selectedItem`. However, NSButton nor NSMenu implement such behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook up selectors and actions for each menu item, and then when you receive the action message you will know what was selected.

By the way, I wonder why you don't use `NSPopUpButton`.  You know you can change the style of `NSPopUpButton` to make it look like other buttons, yes?